# Unresolved reference when using list conprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I am trying to eliminate the duplicates by using list comprehension but i keep getting unresolved reference s

code:

```
l = [[1,4,2],[5,1,4],[2,3,4,5]]
{n for n in s for s in l }
```

Comment: It should be `{n for s in l for n in s}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
{n  for s in l  for n in s}

>> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

You were using the wrong order for the for-loops.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `itertools.chian.from_iterable`:

```
from itertools import chain

l = [[1,4,2],[5,1,4],[2,3,4,5]]

set(chain.from_iterable(l))
```

output:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Comment: Here's timeit analysis : `In [45]: timeit set(chain.from_iterable(l))
591 ns ± 32 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`...`In [47]: timeit {n for s in l for n in s}
653 ns ± 33.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`

Comment: This solution is faster than set comprehension(ignoring the import overhead)

Answer (score 1):

The notation is `{item for inner in outer for item in inner}`

In your case `{n  for s in l  for n in s}`